# Flash Collision Detection (Platformer game)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, game-physics, rectangles

I am trying to make a platformer game in flash, using ActionScript 3. Currently everything is working except for one thing.

The Problem:

When the player collides with the bottom of a platform, if his xVel is not equal to zero, the horizontal collision detection loop is called and the player is moved horizontally as well as vertically. This means he bounces off the platform from underneath but is also displaced to one side of the platform. If the player's xVel is equal to zero, everything works fine. This is because the horizontal collision loop is not called. I cannot figure out why this happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var level:Array = new Array();

var xVel = 0;
var yVel = 0;

var xSpeed = 15;

var accel =1.5;
var grav = 2;
var jumpHeight = 15*grav;


for(var i = 0; i<numChildren;i++){
    if(getChildAt(i) is platform){
        level.push(getChildAt(i).getRect(this));
    }   
}

var upKeyDown = false;
var leftKeyDown = false;
var rightKeyDown = false;
var downKeyDown = false;


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameLoop);

function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        upKeyDown = true;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        leftKeyDown = true;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        rightKeyDown = true;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        downKeyDown = true;
    }   
}
function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        upKeyDown = false;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        leftKeyDown = false;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        rightKeyDown = false;
    }   
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        downKeyDown = false;
    }   
}

function gameLoop(e:Event){
    if(rightKeyDown){
        if(xVel<xSpeed){
            xVel+=accel;
        }

    }else if(leftKeyDown){
        if(xVel>-xSpeed){
            xVel-=accel;
        }

    }else{
        xVel *=0.6;
    }
    //horizontal
    player.x+=xVel;
    for(i = 0; i<level.length;i++){
        if(player.getRect(this).intersects(level[i])){
            if(xVel>0){
                player.x = level[i].left-player.width/2;
            }
            if(xVel<0){
                player.x = level[i].right+player.width/2;
            }
            xVel = 0;
        }
    }

    yVel+=grav;
    player.y+=yVel;
    var jumpable = false;
    for(i = 0; i<level.length;i++){
        if(player.getRect(this).intersects(level[i])){
            if(yVel>0){
                player.y = level[i].top-player.height/2;
                yVel = 0;
                jumpable = true;
            }
            if(yVel<0){
                player.y = level[i].bottom+player.height/2;
                yVel*=-0.5;
            }
        }
    }
    if(upKeyDown&&jumpable){
        jump();
    }
    this.x = -player.x+(stage.stageWidth/2);
    this.y = -player.y+(stage.stageHeight/2);
}

function jump(){
    yVel-=jumpHeight;   
}
```

Where **I think** the problem occurs

```
player.x+=xVel;
    for(i = 0; i<level.length;i++){
        if(player.getRect(this).intersects(level[i])){
            if(xVel>0){
                player.x = level[i].left-player.width/2;
            }
            if(xVel<0){
                player.x = level[i].right+player.width/2;
            }
            xVel = 0;
        }
    }

    yVel+=grav;
    player.y+=yVel;
    var jumpable = false;
    for(i = 0; i<level.length;i++){
        if(player.getRect(this).intersects(level[i])){
            if(yVel>0){
                player.y = level[i].top-player.height/2;
                yVel = 0;
                jumpable = true;
            }
            if(yVel<0){
                player.y = level[i].bottom+player.height/2;
                yVel*=-0.5;
            }
        }
    }
```

The picture!

[image: A visual description]

Extra information:

The platforms are movie clip symbols, all originating from the same symbol. They are dragged onto the canvas and re sized. The platform symbol has an AS linkage called 'platform' which is how the child is identified as a platform in the code

The player is a rectangle with no animations

Both the platforms and player have an orientation in the center of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to to is test the ceiling collision first and adjust accordingly before the horizontal check.  If you don't, then you player is colliding with the bottom of the platform when you do the horizontal check.

Comment: I re positioned the for-loops and nothing changed.

Comment: In your horizontal test loop, how about you turn the alpha of the platform you collide with to .50, so you can see which piece is causing the collision. If it's colliding with the top piece still when you do your check, you have not properly done what I suggested.

Comment: What do you mean 'check which piece'? do you mean the top, left, bottom and right? How do I change it so I can see which piece? Changing the alpha of each symbol just makes them transparent.

Comment: Either that or your math allows for the player to still be colliding with the ceiling platform, even after the collision is handled.

Comment: I am asking you to change the alpha, so it's obvious what piece you collided with. It's a visual aide. If you did what I suggested correctly and your math is right, you should not be colliding with that top platform.

Comment: Is the platform one solid piece ? sorry, I was thinking tiles. But same idea, if you are still colliding with the platform after you handle the y collision, your math is wrong.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the alpha of the platform. Nothing really happened except for now I can see through it. What else do you want me to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28525/discussion-between-prototypical-and-grimrader22)

Comment: ok, if you are setting that platform alpha to .5 in the horizontal collision check, that means that you have not adjusted the player's y position correctly after the vertical collision. If you did, then it would no longer be colliding.